# i want to path optimisation user travel my website particular time in travel in particular time in pig

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

Input Data Set :

```
(2012-07-21T14:00:00.000Z, joe, hxxp:///www.aaa.com/home) 
(2012-07-21T14:01:00.000Z, mary, hxxp:///www.aaa.com/watch)  
(2012-07-21T14:02:00.000Z, joe, hxxp:///www.aaa.com/movie)
(2012-07-21T14:01:00.000Z, mary, hxxp:///www.aaa.com/mobile)
```

Expected Output :

```
(joe (hxxp:///www.aaa.com/home, hxxp:///www.aaa.com/movie))
(mary(hxxp:///www.aaa.com/watch, hxxp:///www.aaa.com/mobile))
```

I want do path analysis projet like this in apache pig

user how to travel  my website , i want to path optimisation 
 user first see that website hxxp:///www.aaa.com/home after 2sec he move to hxxp:///www.aaa.com/movie this page i want analysis user travel my website particular time in-travel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input :**

```
2012-07-21T14:00:00.000Z,joe,hxxp:///www.aaa.com/home
2012-07-21T14:01:00.000Z,mary,hxxp:///www.aaa.com/watch
2012-07-21T14:02:00.000Z,joe,hxxp:///www.aaa.com/movie
2012-07-21T14:01:00.000Z,mary,hxxp:///www.aaa.com/mobile
```

**Pig Script :**

```
user_navigation_data = LOAD 'user_nav_data.csv'  USING  PigStorage(',') AS (time:datetime,user:chararray,url:chararray);
nav_data_grp_user = GROUP user_navigation_data BY user;
user_nav_stats = FOREACH nav_data_grp_user {
      user_navigation_data_ord = ORDER user_navigation_data BY time;
      GENERATE group AS user, BagToString(user_navigation_data_ord.url,'-->') AS urls_accessed;
};
```

**Output : DUMP user_nav_stats :**

```
(joe,hxxp:///www.aaa.com/home-->hxxp:///www.aaa.com/movie)
(mary,hxxp:///www.aaa.com/watch-->hxxp:///www.aaa.com/mobile)
```

Comment: how to change url ( link hxxp:///www.aaa.com/home) into name ( HOME )

Comment: @SivasaravanaKumar : Use regex or string function and extract the last part of the string and change the case.

Comment: @SivasaravanaKumar : If answer helped, you can accept the answer.